# Running test with multiple contract address on a local Ganache blockchain

Tags: contract-development, truffle, ganache, abi

I'm developing with Truffle and Ganache

I have an standard ERC20 ABI that I import in my test file. it only has 3 optionals functions name, symbol and decimals.

```
const Token = artifacts.require('./Token')
```

And I instantiate it

```
token = await Token.new()
```

After this I can call it's functions directly like this

```
token.name()
```

How would I proceed to use the same functions on another ERC20 standard contract? Can I use my contract ABI that is pretty much standard or do I need another contract that will take a contract address as an argument to make the call to the right contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- `token = await Token.new('name', 'symbol', decimals)` in order to deploy and interact with a new `Token` instance
- `token = await Token.at('0xSomeAddress')` in order to interact with an already-deployed `Token` instance

Depending on your Truffle version, the `await` before the `at` may be redundant.

But you can leave it there in order to stay on the safe side.